# Diagnostics in Spline Regression

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, splines, diagnostic

In linear models, we do statistical tests (e.g. normality of residuals, homoskedasticity, autocorrelation, etc.). In spline regression, using the following method, we are running linear regression only. But they are not a single regression equation, but more than 1 equation.

```r
library(splines)
   
x <- runif(100)
y <- sin(2*pi*x) + rnorm(100, 0, 0.3)

xx <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)

fit1 <- lm(y ~ bs(x, degree=1, df=4))

plot(x, y, pch=19)
lines(xx, predict(fit1, newdata=list(x=xx)), col='red')
```

So, my question is, do we use the same set of statistical tests in this case as well? If not, what are different test we can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear model with splines is still a linear model, the change is that the splined variable is split into multiple parts/variables (piecewise terms, depends on the number of knots and what type of spline you select). To see what exactly is going on check the model matrix

```
> round(head(model.matrix(y ~ bs(x, degree=1, df=4)),5),2)
  (Intercept) bs(x, degree = 1, df = 4)1 bs(x, degree = 1, df = 4)2 bs(x, degree = 1, df = 4)3
1           1                       0.00                       0.00                       0.23
2           1                       0.00                       0.22                       0.78
3           1                       0.41                       0.00                       0.00
4           1                       0.00                       0.07                       0.93
5           1                       0.00                       0.00                       0.00
  bs(x, degree = 1, df = 4)4
1                       0.77
2                       0.00
3                       0.00
4                       0.00
5                       1.00
```

As you can see the x variable has been split into 4 new variables (depends also on the `intercept` argument in `bs`). All the regular diagnostics and tests apply here as well, although the tests are now on piecewise terms.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what you meant by "tests are now on piecewise terms"? E.g. for normality, we should still check the normality of the residual, right? Thanks!

Comment: @ragas t-tests on the coefficients are done the same way as in a regular linear model where you are testing whether a coefficient is different than some constant, which are piecewise terms. Diagnostics on the residuals are still done on the whole model, nothing has changed.